# DateTime -> Textbox (jquery!) -> EditorFor (DateTime.ascx) -> add javascript event. How?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I defined this **DateTime.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%: Html.TextBox(   string.Empty, 
                    (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : string.Empty), 
                    new {   @class = "whatever"

                        }
                 )%>
```

and the **aspx site** looks so:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data.birthday) %>
```

The idea is now that a javascript function "ABC()" is called 
when ever the textbox loses the focus (means "onBlur" event)
(ideally: the value of the trextbox is passed to the called function "ABC(birtday.value)")
But I would not like to change the **DateTime.ascx** to end up that ALL(!) EditorFor (for Datetimes) will have an javascript function call!

**My tries:**
This

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data.birthday, "onBlur='javascript:ABC();'", "birthday") %>
```

results in

```
<input class="whatever" id="birthday" name="birthday" type="text" value="25.08.2010" />
```

but the onBlur / javascript function call is **not** set.

And

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data.birthday, new { onClick="javascript:ShowHideC1();"} ) %>
```

doesnt work either.

(Next step is then that this textbox is "of course" a jquery datepicker ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its stupid to answer the own question, but I want to share my knownledge. ;-)

Solution:

DO NOT use the `Html.EditorFor`!

use the `TextBoxesFor`!

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data.birthday, new { onBlur="javascript:ABC();"} )%>
```

Using the TextBoxFor means that the DateTime.ascx is NOT used.
When "...birthday" is set to a non-null value in the Controller is the output not formated as in DateTime.ascx defined. Means also the hours, minutes and times will be displayed.
But the OnBlur - event is added! And that was the goal!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

[MVC 2 Editor Template with DateTime](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx)

Comment: thx for the very fast reply. But there is "just" explained how to handle/expand the datepicker. I need a way to call a javascript function ABC() when ever the datepicker looses focus. Ok. I can expand (somehow) the 5 already existing jquery events. But then i have the problem to raise this newly added jquery event? (we are circling, arent we?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html.EditorFor, but you will have to bind the events separately:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 // bind events to template editors
 $("#Data_birthday").bind('blur', ABC);
 $("#Data_birthday").bind('click', ShowHideC1);
}
```